# Ensuring that methods inside a block finishes executing before calling another method

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, objective-c-blocks

I currently have the following two methods, the first of which is only called when the user is new and perform initial setups by saving user preferences to the cloud, and the second is called every time when the user uses the app by performing queries based on the user's preferences.

```
[self doInitialSetupsForNewUser]; //Only happens for new user.  Performs query on a block
[self getUserPrefsAndDoStuff]; //For all users
```

While the method `getUserPrefsAndDoStuff` works fine, it fails to do its job if the user is brand new and the set up method must be called first.  Inside `doInitialSetupsForNewUser`, I make the following call to Facebook using the block:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){ ... }
}];
```

My issue is, due to the block structure, `getUserPrefsAndDoStuff` is called prematurely before the user's preferences are downloaded and saved in the block in `doInitialSetupsForNewUser`, and therefore is pulling incorrect data.  How do I ensure that the setup block completes execution prior to `getUserPrefsAndDoStuff`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify `doInitialSetupsForNewUser` to take its own completion block then it is prety easy to do. It would look something like this.

```
- (void)doInitialSetupsForNewUser:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion
{
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            ...
            completion(YES, nil);
        } else {
            completion(NO, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Then you just need to change the code that calls it so that is uses the completion block to get the prefs.

```
if (newUser) {
    [self doInitialSetupsForNewUser:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success)
            [self getUserPrefsAndDoStuff];
        else
            NSLog(@"oh no!  %@", error);
    }];
}
else {
    [self getUserPrefsAndDoStuff];
}
```

Comment: good answer, but have that doInitialSetupsForNewUser pass on some notion of success, maybe (BOOL success, NSError *error).

Comment: Perfect, and an elegant solution!  @danh - would you mind modifying the answer to show what you mean by including the notion of success?  I'm very new to iOS so concrete examples help a lot - thanks to you both!

Comment: @daspianist  ok.  I did the edit without a compiler, but it passes a desk check.